# /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 is not ready or not present

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, system-installation

This is frustrating as heck, I moved away from Windows 7 OS because of issues, errors, and such and was sold to Ubuntu because it was supposed to be reliable, and now errors and issues right after installing 12.04 with `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` and then got 13.10 to replace it, hoping issue was gone and now it's still here anyway but different message reference.

I only have ONE hard drive, it's 1TB and it only had Windows 7 on it and was never really used at all. I formatted it during both Ubuntu version installations. So not sure WHY this issue keeps sporadically happening...!? It's not happening all the time though, just here and there after the computer has been shut off for few hours each time.

My output for `cat /etc/fstab` is...

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=737f749f-8ef5-4744-953f-81422ffc9000 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

My output for `sudo blkid` is...

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="737f749f-8ef5-4744-953f-81422ffc9000" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="12bd13d8-f3ac-4606-828b-671c396d36f5" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: UUID="jdUrXq-YfKr-eB52-oPOv-NLks-nyBK-p5ER2H" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="2b450222-9a24-4c38-97aa-e4d2e83e94c6" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="59fa5eff-d30f-4d1a-aa97-46fec43e805c" TYPE="swap"
```

I'm just not sure WHY this issue would be happening though, it doesn't make sense. The hard drive itself should be fine, reads as healthy and etc. Ubuntu SHOULD be correctly assigning the privileges, running swap right, and etc. Starting to wonder if I should just go back to Windows 7, or Linux Mint, or some other Linux OS but they have same issues I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

To get the moose, format the linear virtual block device:

- Boot into recovery mode
- Select Drop to root shell prompt
- mount drive in read-write mode: `mount -o remount, rw /`

Check it:

```
$ dmsetup -v table /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

Turn off swap:

```
$ swapoff -a
```

Format the swapfile:

```
$ mkswap /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` and Comment out any other swap files:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
#/swapfile1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Reboot.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>

Was the swap file allocated to swap by fstab? We should have 888MB:

```
$ free

Swap:       909308      0     909308
```

Is the linear virtual block device encrypted? dmsetup will return "crypt":

```
$ dmsetup status

sda5_crypt: 0 624637944 crypt
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. I made a new one:

- Boot into recovery mode
- Select Drop to root shell prompt
- mount drive in read-write mode: `mount -o remount, rw /`

Make a swap file:

```
fallocate -l 512m /swapfile1.swp
```

Format the new swapfile

```
$ mkswap /swapfile1.swp
```

Change the permissions:

```
$ chown root:root /swapfile1.swp

$ chmod 0600 /swapfile1swp
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` and Comment out the mapper:

```
#/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Reboot.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>

Was the swap file allocated to swap by fstab? We should have 512MB:

```
$ free
Swap:       524280      17148     507132
```